# Как убрать переход на страницу обработчика формы?

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</>
</form>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы перехода на mail.php не было

Comment: ajax, либо target="iframe"

<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

Comment: но в этом случае ничего не отправиться

    <form action="mail.php" onsubmit="return false;">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте для формы `name="formName"` и добавьте нужную функцию для `submit`:

```
document.formName.submit=function(){
    //любые действия
    return false;//чтобы не отправлять запрос
}
```

Если "любые действия" включают в себя отправку формы, то можно:

а) использовать `ajax` — с помощью метода [`jQuery.ajax(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) или [`XMLHTTPRequest`](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/);

б) отправлять форму через загрузку скрипта с нужным `url` (такое обычно используют, если результат возвращается в формате `json`), тоесть:

```
var script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');
script.src='нужны адрес?параметры';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```